# Visual Studio Code JDK 13

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a tiny question regarding to vs code:

Can I set the default eclipse settings in classpath and settings to java 13, because it's always set to java 1.8 and I have to change it manually.

[image: .classpath][image: settings]

Comment: To be clear, you want to set JDK13 for eclipse compilation? Is your eclipse project a maven project?

Comment: No, it is a normal Java project. I have already set the right class path etc. In vscode the  java extension just generates the settings for java 1.8. For example in the 2nd picture I had to replace "orc.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8" with "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=13".

Comment: have you tried to change the  `"java.home"` in the `.settings.json`  ?

Comment: Once you ensure VSC Java extensions are running with JDK 13, then when you create a Java project, it should have the target for 13.

Comment: yes, I use the path to the right jdk @LeoZhu-MSFT